# Error with H3DNodeDatabase PhantomDevice::database in PhantomDevice.cpp

Tags: c++, dllimport, hapi, haptic-feedback

I am using C++ to establish a connection with Sensable Phantom Omni haptic device with H3D toolkit. These lines of code give me some challenges and will not compile successfully:

```
#include <H3D/PhantomDevice.h>
#include <HAPI/PhantomHapticsDevice.h>

using namespace H3D;
...
H3DNodeDatabase PhantomDevice::database("PhantomDevice", &(newInstance<PhantomDevice>),typeid(PhantomDevice),&H3DHapticsDevice::database);  //line 36
namespace PhantomDeviceInternals {...}
unsigned int PhantomDevice::nr_initialized_devices = 0;  //line 60
bool PhantomDevice::started_scheduler = false;          //line 61
unsigned int PhantomDevice::render_shapes_called = 0;  //line 62
...
```

The resulting error messages are:

I have the following errors:

```
PhantomDevice.cpp:36: error: definition of static data member 'H3D::PhantomDevice::database' of dllimport'd class.
PhantomDevice.cpp:60: error: definition of static data member 'H3D::PhantomDevice::nr_initialized_devices' of dllimport'd class.
PhantomDevice.cpp:61: error: definition of static data member 'H3D::PhantomDevice::started_scheduler' of dllimport'd class.
PhantomDevice.cpp:62: error: definition of static data member 'H3D::PhantomDevice::render_shapes_called' of dllimport'd class.
make.exe: *** [PhantomDevice.o] Error 1
```

Please anyone can suggest what to do as I am stuck in the mud now.

Comment: Why are you trying to define static members of a class that comes from a library?

Comment: The variables are defined as protected static in the library. I only defined and initialized as:  
    unsigned int PhantomDevice::nr_initialized_devices = 0;  bool PhantomDevice::started_scheduler = false;          
    unsigned int PhantomDevice::render_shapes_called = 0;

Comment: They're defined in the library.  You should not be defining them.

Comment: I changed the LoCs to:
    PhantomDevice::nr_initialized_devices = 0;
    PhantomDevice::started_scheduler = false;
    PhantomDevice::render_shapes_called = 0;

I got these errors:
    PhantomDevice.cpp:36: error: definition of static data member 'H3D::PhantomDevice::database' of dllimport'd class.
    PhantomDevice.cpp:57: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token
    PhantomDevice.cpp:57: error: expected `,' or `;' before '=' token
    PhantomDevice.cpp:58: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token
Please Check!